# Can we assign a string value to "const char *var" in C langauage?

Tags: c, string

Can we assign a string value directly to const char * ? why memory allocation is not required here ?

For example:

```
const char *var = "Hello";
```

Comment: You don't need a memory allocation because string literals always exist, and decay to a pointer to `char`.

Comment: The *compiler* is allocating the space for it and storing it in a readonly section of memory, then handing its address to `var`

Comment: In a nutshell, memory allocation is not required because the compiler already knows how big the string "Hello" is.  The literal string "Hello" is a compile-time concept; `malloc` happens at run time.

Comment: You are not assigning a string to `var`. You are assigning a *pointer* to `var`, the address of the first character in `"Hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why memory allocation is not required here?

All implementations of C memory allocation are different, but typically on a PC the executable file itself is part of the memory space. `Hello` is stored in the executable file and can be addressed as memory.

If you examine the executable file with an editor you should find `Hello`. You can also use the [`strings`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_(Unix)) utility to find the strings stored in an executable.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *string = "Hello";
    puts(string);
}

$ cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c11 -pedantic -O3 -c -o test.o test.c

$ cc   test.o   -o test

$ strings test
Hello
```

If you look at the `var` pointer, `printf("%p\n, var)`, you will see that it is much smaller than other pointers. This is how the various memory spaces are separated, by assigning them ranges of pointers. Memory assigned to the executable file is typically "low", memory in the stack is "high", and dynamic memory (ie. `malloc`) is somewhere in between.

See [Memory Layout of C Programs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/) for more detail.